# How can I create expression to be used in another expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, expression, expression-trees

I use Linq2Sql to access DB and Repository pattern implemented for that.

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T, TDb> : IRepository<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return GetTable().Select(GetConverter());
    }
}

public class ProductRepository
    : RepositoryBase<IProduct, DbData.Product>
{
    protected override Table<DbData.Product> GetTable()
    {
        return Context.CustomerProducts;
    }

    protected override Expression<Func<DbData.Product, IProduct>> GetConverter()
    {
        return dbEntity =>
             (ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.MyType
                    ? (new Product1{...}) as IProduct
                    : (new Product2{...}) as IProduct
    }
}
```

I need to modify mentioned code in this way:

```
    protected override Expression<Func<DbData.Product, IProduct>> GetConverter()
    {
        return dbEntity => 
             (ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.MyType
             || (ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.My2ndType
             || (ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.My3rdType
                    ? (new Product1{...}) as IProduct
                    : (new Product2{...}) as IProduct
    }
```

As I will have same check in other places I would like to separate a function:

```
public static bool IsProductOfType1(ProdType.ProdTypeEnum eProdTypeId)
{
    return eProdTypeIdd==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.MyType
             || eProdTypeId==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.My2ndType
             || eProdTypeId==ProdType.ProdTypeEnum.My3rdType
}


    protected override Expression<Func<DbData.Product, IProduct>> GetConverter()
    {
        return dbEntity => 
             IsProductOfType1((ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId)
                    ? (new Product1{...}) as IProduct
                    : (new Product2{...}) as IProduct
    }
```

The following case throws an exception:

> Method 'Boolean IsProductOfType1(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL

It seems like inside of 'GetConverter' method I need to use not a method, but an expression. But I don't know what is syntax of that.

Please advise. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
public static bool IsProductOfType1(ProdType.ProdTypeEnum eProdTypeId)
```

This method should return an `Expression<T>` instead of `bool`. Any call to external methods won't be converter by `LINQ to SQL`

Comment: How could I use this method inside of 'GetConverter()' method? I can't use it as a usual method (as it requires compilation before usage). But once I  compile it I will get the same error (guess).

Comment: Not quite familiar with expressions, but, can't you change `IsProductOfType1` to return an expression so that you can use it something like `IsProductOfType1()((ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId)`?

Comment: You can't pass a parameter to expression. You would be correct if you right something like this: IsProductOfType1().Compile()((ProdType.ProdTypeEnum)dbEntity.ProdId). But as I told that will be almost equal to just calling method